# MS Access: Selecting the first item according to a rank

Tags: sql, ms-access

Imagine I have a query called QueryA that returns stuff like this:

```
Employee    Description   Rank
John        Happy         1
John        Depressed     3
James       Happy         1
James       Confused      2
Mark        Depressed     3
```

I am trying to make a query that grabs the Employee and the Description, but only one description -- the one with the best "rank." (the lower the rank the better). I sort QueryA by Employee then by Rank (descending).

So I'd want my new query QueryB to show that John as Happy, James as Happy, and Mark as Depressed.

However I try selecting Employee and then First of Description and it doesn't always work.

Comment: Have you tried using MIN(Rank)?

Comment: @durbnpoisn I tried min but somehow it still included multiple descriptions. I only want one description per employee.

Comment: Let me know if my edits work in Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to check this for Access, but it should work fine.  Check my [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ae7a/8)

```
select
  r.employee, d.description
from
  table1 as d
  inner join (select min(rank) as rank, employee
              from
                 table1
              group by employee) r on d.rank = r.rank
                                      and d.employee = r.employee
```

Comment: I am trying to get the employee and the highest-ranked description, not the employee and the rank

Comment: @user3219632 its customary to upvote your answer as well. :) Thanks! Glad it worked out.